# namespace with static data memeber of structure aving ordering issue

Tags: c++, object, c++11, namespaces, static-members

I have the code as below with which i experience static object order creation issue.

### h1.hpp

```
namespace X {

   struct XX {
        static const string str1;
        static const string str2;
   };
}
```

### h1.cpp

```
namespace X {

        const string XX::str1 = "Hello World";
        const string XX:str2  = "Hello Country";
    }

h2.cpp ----> included h1.hpp
h3.cpp ----> included h1.hpp
h4.cpp ----> included h1.hpp
------
```

I would like to access it as, [X::XX::str1]

```
func1(X::XX::str1); etc.
```

What is the best approach, as the one above gives me some static object creation order issue, when i try to access X::XX::str1 i get empty instead of "Hello World". How can i make sure same object (X::XX:str1) is being used not every where a local copy created.

### Updated info:

Actually when i access X::XX::str1 program segfaults. So object is not created?

Comment: Provide a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org)!

Comment: Is this the actual code? Missing semi-colon in `struct` definition.

Comment: [This works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=93335ef12bfa332ec160d96f59e2f943-8996fa4eaf2a653a1ca8b32f107442f6)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Static initialization troubles usually only appear when more than one TU is involved.

Comment: @pmr: Yes this is my problem, even when i create a object these static members wont get created couldnt understand why and my application segfaults.

Comment: @s.s Does my work-around help?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. There can only be a static order initialization problem if you call `func1` from a constructor of another static object.

If this is the case, you can make accesses to the static variables in `XX` go through static member functions that return references to a function local static variable. Calling the function will guarantee that the objects are initialized.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct XX {
  static std::string& str1() 
  { static std::string x = "Hello World"; return x; }
  static std::string& str2() 
  { static std::string x = "Hello Country"; return x; }
};

int main()
{
  std::string& x = XX::str1();
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
  std::cout << XX::str2() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```